# Python files not running in VScode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio

I created this the other day and had no errors. It ran perfectly fine. All of a sudden I can't run any saved files and when i create new ones python doesn't seem to work anymore. This is what it shows me. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
[code that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWqEr.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your shell cannot find the Python interpreter.

If you are using bash as your shell, check .bashrc in your home directory. You can `ls -laF` to see all the hidden files. Make sure you have the correct Python path that looks something like `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/foo`

Comment: Normally you should not have to set PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal application.

In it, issue the command `which python`.
If that returns the location of python, check that this location is in your evironment variable `PATH`.

If `which` returns "not found", try `which python3` instead.
If that returns a location, change your VScode settings to use `python3` instead of `python`.